# How to work with foundry anvil custom rpc methods?

Tags: evm, foundry, rpc, anvil

I'm running an anvil fork node on localhost:8545, and I create a provider by ethers:

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('http://localhost:8545')
```

I tried some common rpc methods like: eth_chainId, eth_networkId, eth_blockNumber,... All of them work well. But when I tried some anvil custom rpc methods, they cause problems. Example:

```
await provider.send('anvil_reset')
=> Uncaught:
Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32603, "message": "Not implemented" }, payload={ "id": 15, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "anvil_reset", "params": null }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.7.1)
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (/Users/dangcongtan/AvacusCC/evm-tx-inspector/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/providers/provider-jsonrpc.ts:976:25)
    at makeError (/Users/dangcongtan/AvacusCC/evm-tx-inspector/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:685:21) {
  code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
  error: { code: -32603, message: 'Not implemented' },
  payload: { method: 'anvil_reset', params: undefined, id: 15, jsonrpc: '2.0' }
}
```

or

```
await provider.send('anvil_autoImpersonateAccount', [true]);
=> Uncaught:
Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32601, "message": "Method not found" }, payload={ "id": 16, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "anvil_autoImpersonateAccount", "params": [ true ] }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.7.1)
    at JsonRpcProvider.getRpcError (/Users/dangcongtan/AvacusCC/evm-tx-inspector/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/providers/provider-jsonrpc.ts:976:25)
    at makeError (/Users/dangcongtan/AvacusCC/evm-tx-inspector/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:685:21) {
  code: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
  error: { code: -32601, message: 'Method not found' },
  payload: {
    method: 'anvil_autoImpersonateAccount',
    params: [ true ],
    id: 16,
    jsonrpc: '2.0'
  }
}
```

Anyone know what are problems here? And how to solve them?

Comment: can you provide details regarding how you're starting your anvil node? IIRC certain methods such as `anvil_reset` only work on a forked node.